# Populate Data into a Specific column in CSV Powershell

Tags: powershell

So I'm trying to add values to a CSV file. The code below works however it places the value in $department at the bottom of the file, but in the correct column. Does anyone have any advice on how I can get the value from $deparment to append to the top of the column in the CSV? My code is below:

```
$users = Import-Csv $file -Delimiter ","
$column_number = 6
foreach($user in $users){
    $name = $user.Name

        $department = Get-ADUser -Identity $name -Properties Department | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Department
        Add-Content $file -Value "$(","*$column_number)$department"

}
```

Comment: Fixed it!```foreach($user in $users){
        $name = $user.Name
        $department = Get-ADUser -Identity $name -Properties Department | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Department
        $RowIndex = [array]::IndexOf($users.Department, " ")
        $user[$RowIndex].Department = $department
        
        
}```

Comment: And then save the CSV```$Users | Export-csv $file -NoTypeInformation```